# I want to invest in Asian technological firms. In which ETFs or other product should I invest?

Tags: investing, etf, stock-markets

I am looking for an Asian Nasdaq index or something like that. Maybe investing directly in the US market where some of the largest Chinese companies IPO have taken place makes sense. Any insights?

Comment: Your question as written will be closed because it asks for us to make your investment decisions ("In which ETFs should I invest?")  But you can salvage it by asking how to find ETFs that meet both criteria: region (Asia) and sector (technology)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of web sites that offer ETF information.  One of them that I have used is  [ETFDB](https://etfdb.com/etfs/region/developed-asia-pacific/).  It has a free screener.  For example, it shows that there are 121 Asian ETFs for Developed Asia.

There are other screening choices as well. You can select an ETF and click on is holdings.  That will provide the major holdings.  It requires a subscription if  you want to  export the entire list of holdings,