# How to find ETFs that meet both criteria: region (Asia/ China) and sector (technology)?

Tags: investing, etf

Is there a Chinese stock index comparable to the NASDAQ 100 or NASDAQ Composite covering Chinese technology stocks with the highest market cap? And are there corresponding ETFs or Mutual Funds?

Comment: How is this different than your [prior question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/112508) (which was closed but had a reasonable answer)?

Comment: It's different because it has a few less words in the question ??? :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to invest in Asian technological firms. In which ETFs or other product should I invest?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/112508/i-want-to-invest-in-asian-technological-firms-in-which-etfs-or-other-product-sh)

Comment: @DStanley The OP might have misunderstood the comment posted on the other question as “ask a new question” instead of “edit the existing question”, which is what I presume the commenter intended.

Comment: @DStanley: It's rather different because the last one asked us to pick for him from the universe of possible funds (an answer to the actual question would need to predict the future by considering all criteria -- expenses, management, risk, etc, without even a fraction of the information about OP needed to make a choice), while this one is only about how to approach narrowing down the universe on two specific criteria, and leaves actually doing the research, weighing other criteria, and making the final selection all to OP.

Answer (score 1):

The two that I'm familiar with are KWEB and CQQQ, both of which are Chinese Tech/Internet stock ETF's.

If you want to find and research other ETF's, [this site](https://etfdb.com/screener/) has a good screener. You can screen by asset class, stock type, sector, country, etc.

From there, you can look at the individual equities that comprise the ETF to see if they're inline with what you're looking for.